# Memoir, how to make \makechapterstyle aware if chapter title is in frontmatter?

Tags: memoir, chapters

for my book i define own chapter style which i like to use only in body of document (after `\mainmatter`). in front matter i like to preserve default memoir chapter style.

**background:**

my chapter style gives the following result:

[image]

in the front matter i increase text width to the right border of chapter title (see mwe below). consequently chapter title is pushed out of page (in this case title of table of content, i.e.: "Content").

[image]

to make it visible, i looking for how to make my chapter style aware, where is used. for star i like to have in front matter `memoir` default style.

**mwe:**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shadows}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \newlength{\marginwidth}
    \setlength{\marginwidth}{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
    \newsavebox{\bookbox}
    \newcommand{\zfcbookname}[1]{\sbox{\bookbox}{\textsc{#1}}}
    \zfcbookname{<book title>}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\makechapterstyle{zfcBook}{%
\setlength\beforechapskip{9\baselineskip}
\setlength\afterchapskip{7\baselineskip}
\setlength\midchapskip{1\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\chaptitlefont}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\bfseries\fontsize{77}{84}\selectfont}
        \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
    \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
        \begin{adjustwidth}{\marginwidth}{-\marginwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
%-------
\node[name=chapter,
      rectangle,fill=white,minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=22mm,
      copy shadow={shadow xshift=6pt,shadow yshift=-2pt,fill=black}] {~};
\node[above left] at (chapter.south east) {
            \ifanappendix\chaptitlefont\@chapapp\fi
            \chapnumfont\thechapter};
\node[below right=1mm and 0mm] at (chapter.south west) {\usebox{\bookbox}};
%-------
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{adjustwidth}
                                   }%end od print chapter num
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{
        \begin{adjustwidth}{\marginwidth}{-\marginwidth}
    \raggedleft{\chaptitlefont ##1}\par\nobreak%
        \end{adjustwidth}
                                        }% end of print chapter title
                            }%end of zfcBook
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapterstyle{zfcBook}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frontmatter
\changetext{0pt}{\marginwidth}{-\marginwidth}{0pt}{0pt}
\tableofcontents                                % kazalo
\changetext{0pt}{-\marginwidth}{\marginwidth}{0pt}{0pt}
\mainmatter

\chapter{ena}
\lipsum[11]
    \section{ena ena}
    \section{ena dva}
    \section{ena tri}
\chapter{dva}
    \section{dva ena}
    \section{dva dva}
    \section{dva tri}
\end{document}
```

**question:**

how to change my `\makechapterstyle` that it will be aware of `\frontmatter` and there use or default memoir style or new defined style (very different from one used in `\mainmatter`)?

Comment: i just "discover" a simple solution: move `\chapterstyle{zfcBook}` after `\mainmatter` ... it seems that i should delete my question :-(

Comment: Inside `\frontmatter` the numbered version is not used, so you can add stuff to `\printchapternonum`, which will be executed under `\chapter*` and within frontmatter. I sometimes add a switch in `\printchapternonum` when I have all the typesetting (name and number) inside `\printchaptertitle`, then I can distinguish between the two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `\if@mainmatter...\else ...\fi` inside `\makechapterstyle` help?

`\frontmatter` sets `\@mainmatterfalse`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shadows}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \newlength{\marginwidth}
    \setlength{\marginwidth}{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
    \newsavebox{\bookbox}
    \newcommand{\zfcbookname}[1]{\sbox{\bookbox}{\textsc{#1}}}
    \zfcbookname{<book title>}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{zfcBook}{%
  \if@mainmatter
  \setlength\beforechapskip{9\baselineskip}
  \setlength\afterchapskip{7\baselineskip}
  \setlength\midchapskip{1\baselineskip}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\chaptitlefont}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\bfseries\fontsize{77}{84}\selectfont}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{\marginwidth}{-\marginwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
%-------
        \node[name=chapter,
        rectangle,fill=white,minimum width=\textwidth,minimum height=22mm,
        copy shadow={shadow xshift=6pt,shadow yshift=-2pt,fill=black}] {~};
        \node[above left] at (chapter.south east) {
          \ifanappendix\chaptitlefont\@chapapp\fi
          \chapnumfont\thechapter};
        \node[below right=1mm and 0mm] at (chapter.south west) {\usebox{\bookbox}};
        % -------
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustwidth}
  }%end od print chapter num
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{
    \begin{adjustwidth}{\marginwidth}{-\marginwidth}
      \raggedleft{\chaptitlefont ##1}\par\nobreak%
    \end{adjustwidth}
  }% end of print chapter title
  \else
  \chapterstyle{default}% Is done anyway...
  \fi
}%end of zfcBook
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapterstyle{zfcBook}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frontmatter
\changetext{0pt}{\marginwidth}{-\marginwidth}{0pt}{0pt}
\tableofcontents                                % kazalo
\changetext{0pt}{-\marginwidth}{\marginwidth}{0pt}{0pt}
\mainmatter

\chapter{ena}
\lipsum[11]
    \section{ena ena}
    \section{ena dva}
    \section{ena tri}
\chapter{dva}
    \section{dva ena}
    \section{dva dva}
    \section{dva tri}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, on first i looking exactly for this, so i will accept your answer. but meanwhile i found simple solution (see my comment below question). it seems that due to holidays my brain is not full operational :-).